# drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:' is deprecated

Tags: ios7, ios9

```
[[Util prettyDuration:self.mapBuilding.pendingBuild.secondsRemaining] drawInRect:CGRectMake(5.0, 0.0, 90.0, 15.0) withFont:TIME_FONT lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

[[Util prettyDuration:self.mapBuilding.work.secondsRemaining] drawInRect:CGRectMake(5.0, 20.0, 90.0, 15.0) withFont:TIME_FONT lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

[[self.mapBuilding.level stringValue] drawInRect:CGRectMake(30.0, 40.0, 40.0, 20.0) withFont:LEVEL_FONT lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

In this code I am getting the below warning in iOS 8:

> drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:' is deprecated: first
>   deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use -drawInRect:withAttributes:

How do I remove these warnings? I suspect the solution is the same for all 3 of them but not entirely sure.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822892/drawinrectwithfontlinebreakmodealignment-is-deprecated-warning

Comment: @Hühn0rNüd3lSüpp3 I tried that but I struggled to implement it correctly.